# how to call handleSubmit from parent in redux-form

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I have a problem I can't solve trying to use redux-form. I'm trying the Erikras boilerplate. I want the form to be a component and the parent to call handleSubmit (for the moment with a console.log just to confirm it works). Here, the two:

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import {initialize} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as membersActions from 'redux/modules/members';
import {isLoaded, loadMembers} from 'redux/modules/members';
import { DashboardList } from 'components';
import { DashboardHeader } from 'components';
import { DashboardAdding } from 'components';
import { asyncConnect } from 'redux-async-connect';

@asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({store: {dispatch, getState}}) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadMembers());
    }
  }
}])
@connect(
  state => ({
    members: state.members.data,
    error: state.members.error,
    loading: state.members.loading
  }),
  {...membersActions, initialize })
export default class Dashboard extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    initialize: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    members: PropTypes.array,
    loadMembers: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  handleSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.props.initialize('dashAdding', {});
  }

  handleInitialize = () => {
    this.props.initialize('dashAdding', {
      pseudo: 'Pibo',
      email: 'pibirino@gmail.com'
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {members} = this.props;
     return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <Helmet title="Dashboard"/>
        <DashboardHeader />
        <div>
          <DashboardList members={members}/>
          <h3>Ici commence le form</h3>
          <div style={{textAlign: 'center', margin: 15}}>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleInitialize}>
             <i className="fa fa-pencil"/> Initialize Form
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <DashboardAdding onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
        <p>Bleeeeah!!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here the child:

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import memberValidation from './memberValidation';

@reduxForm({
 form: 'dashAdding',
 fields: ['pseudo', 'email'],
  validate: memberValidation
})

export default class DashboardAdding extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
   fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   resetForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const {
       fields: { pseudo, email},
       handleSubmit,
       resetForm
   } = this.props;
    const renderInput = (field, label) =>
     <div className={'form-group' + (field.error && field.touched ? ' has-error' : '')}>
        <label htmlFor={field.name} className="col-sm-2">{label}</label>
        <div className={'col-sm-8 '}>
           <input type="text" className="form-control" id={field.name} {...field}/>
        </div>
      </div>;

    return (
     <div>
        <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {renderInput(pseudo, 'Full Name')}
          {renderInput(email, 'Email', true)}
          <div className="form-group">
           <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                <i className="fa fa-paper-plane"/> Submit
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={resetForm} style={{marginLeft: 15}}>
                <i className="fa fa-undo"/> Reset
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So... it doesn't work I think I'm missing some important knowledge. I thought that the reason is because the form component is dumb, and it doesn't have the dispatch function. So, I tryed to add this (several times in several different ways) importing the action creator from the specific folder:

```js
@connect(() => ({}),
  dispatch => actionCreators( dispatch)
)
```

But I don't still get what I want. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found the answer by myself. In fact, I decided to not use @connect, whitch is deprecated (despite it's still used in the boilerplate) and to use connect, as in the example of the redux-form documentation. The only change concerned the parent, but I'll post them both in case I missed something. The following code works good.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import {initialize} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as membersActions from 'redux/modules/members';
import {isLoaded, loadMembers} from 'redux/modules/members';
import { DashboardList } from 'components';
import { DashboardHeader } from 'components';
import { DashboardAdding } from 'components';
import { asyncConnect } from 'redux-async-connect';

@asyncConnect([{
  deferred: true,
  promise: ({store: {dispatch, getState}}) => {
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      return dispatch(loadMembers());
    }
  }
}])

class Dashboard extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    members: PropTypes.array,
    error: PropTypes.string,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    addMember: PropTypes.func,
    initialize: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    newMemberData: PropTypes.object
  }

  handleSubmit = (data, dispatch) => {
    dispatch(addMember(JSON.stringify(data)));
    this.props.initialize('dashboardForm', {});
  }

  handleInitialize = () => {
    this.props.initialize('dashboardForm', {
      pseudo: 'Pibo',
      email: 'pibirino@gmail.com'
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {members} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <Helmet title="Dashboard"/>
        <DashboardHeader />
        <div>
          <DashboardList members={members}/>
          <h3>Ici commence le form</h3>
          <div style={{textAlign: 'center', margin: 15}}>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleInitialize}>
              <i className="fa fa-pencil"/> Initialize Form
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <DashboardAdding onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
     members: state.members.data,
    error: state.members.error,
    loading: state.members.loading,
    newMemberData: state.addSingleMember.data
  };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    addActions,
    initialize: initialize
  }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

...and the child component:

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form'; 
import memberValidation from './memberValidation';

class DashboardAdding extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    resetForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const {
        fields: { pseudo, email},
        handleSubmit,
        resetForm
    } = this.props;
     const renderInput = (field, label) =>
      <div className={'form-group' + (field.error && field.touched ? ' has-error' : '')}>
        <label htmlFor={field.name} className="col-sm-2">{label}</label>
        <div className={'col-sm-8 '}>
           <input type="text" className="form-control" id={field.name} {...field}/>
          {field.error && field.touched && <div className="text-danger">{field.error}</div>}
        </div>
      </div>;

    return (
      <div>
         <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          {renderInput(pseudo, 'Pseudo')}
          {renderInput(email, 'Email', true)}
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                <i className="fa fa-paper-plane"/> Submit
              </button>
              <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={resetForm} style={{marginLeft: 15}}>
               <i className="fa fa-undo"/> Reset
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'dashboardForm',
  fields: ['pseudo', 'email'],
  validate: memberValidation,
  asyncBlurFields: ['email']
})(DashboardAdding);
```

The addMember function contains obviously a promise.
I hope it will helps somebody :-)